# SQL Server datetime not recognized by VBA's IsDate function

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, datetime

A SQL Server `datetime` value is represented as `2015-01-29 19:23:00.000` (for example) in a CSV file.

Unfortunately, VBA's `IsDate` function doesn't recognize this as a valid date when it is evaluated in an Excel macro (I'm guessing because of the fractional seconds).  `DateValue` also fails to convert the value.

Is there a VBA tweak to make this work or do I need to strip the fractional seconds?

** edit **

To further complicate matters, the `ActiveCell.Value` converts a text value (e.g. `2015-05-20 15:31:30.000`) to a decimal (e.g. `42144.4166666667`).  As such, the `Evaluate` trick won't work.

To better illustrate the situation, here's the code:

```
'
' format a CSV file for better readability
'
Sub FormatCSV

  ' move top-left corner
  Range("A2").Select

  ' while the current cell's value is not empty
  Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

    ' 2015-05-20 15:31:30.000 => 42144.4166666667
    Debug.Print ActiveCell.Value

    ' if the cell contains a date
    If IsDate(ActiveCell) Then

      ' format entire column as date/time
      ActiveCell.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy hh:mm"

    End If

    ' resize
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    ' move a column to the right
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

  Loop

  ' move top-left corner
  Range("A2").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting because `Evaluate("=DateValue(""2015-01-29 19:23:00.000"")")` works

Answer (score 3):

Seems that VBA does not like the fractional time within the date string.

You can do one of the following:

1. Strip out the fractional time as you already noted.
2. Or you can wrap it with `CDate(Evaluate("=DateValue(""2015-01-29 19:23:00.000"")"))`

Here is a samble VBA Sub:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim d As String
    Dim v As Variant
    d = "2015-01-29 19:23:00.000"
    v = CDate(Evaluate("=DateValue(""" + d + """)"))
    Debug.Print IsDate(v)
    Debug.Print v
End Sub
```

This prints out:

> True
>   1/29/2015

Answer (score 3):

same as in `@chancea` post, but has some difference

```
Sub test()
    Dim d$, a As Date, b As Date, c As Date, da As Date
    d = "2015-01-29 19:23:00.000"
    a = CDate(DateValue(Split(d, " ")(0)))
    b = CDate(DateValue(Left(d, 10)))
    c = CDate(DateValue(Mid(d, 1, 10)))
    da = DateSerial(Split(d, "-")(0), Split(d, "-")(1), Left(Split(d, "-")(2), 2))
    Debug.Print IsDate(a), IsDate(b), IsDate(c), IsDate(da)
    Debug.Print a, b, c, da
End Sub
```

output

[image]